# What is real use of vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Increment/ classes

Tags: magento2, database, eav

I have found some classes under `vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Increment/`, which use I am not sure. Do they serve for incrementing id's values of new rows in EAV tables? Or this process is fullfilled by `mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do they serve for incrementing id's values of new rows in EAV table

Sort of. Not for the primary keys (`entity_id`), but for custom ids, like order number, invoice number and customer number. Using these different models you can customize the logic of these ids.

This is configured at database level. Take a look at the tables `eav_entity_type` and `eav_entity_store` to see, how.

Comment: from `sales_invoice` column `icrement_id` can be an example?

Comment: Yes, the `increment_id` columns are populated like that